# How would I display Pushpins Based on this KML/XML

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pushpin

I current have a KML File with each location written as below.

```
  <Placemark>
    <name>Placemark 1</name>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#style6</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>174.732224,-36.931053,0.000000</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

I am looking for a way to bind the coordinates to Pushpins using datatemaplte binding and XML parsing.

I have seen quite a few other examples, but all using lat and long values, not a combined coordinates like above.

I assume the XAMl would be something like this.

```
<my:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location, Converter={...}}"
            Content="{Binding}" />
```

Does anyone have any idea how I would parse this KML correctly to bind the location?

This is for WIndows Phone 7

If you need clarification please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) is your friend!

```
var geoData = coordinates.Split(',');
var latitude = double.Parse(geoData[0]);
var longitude = double.Parse(geoData[1]);
var altitude = double.Parse(geoData[2]);
```

Comment: Do I need to sperate them? Can I not just bind then coordinates as a full location?

Comment: Yes, yes, I know you have already said this and I am learning. I am sure you had to start somewhere too.